# WPF UserControls - setting the .Command property on button inside UserControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, command

I've got a UserControl that contains a button and some other controls:

```
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
     <Button x:Name="button" />
     ...
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

When I create a new instance of that control, I want to get at the Button's Command property:

```
<my:GreatUserControl TheButton.Command="{Binding SomeCommandHere}">
</my:GreatUserControl>
```

Of course, the "TheButton.Command" thing doesn't work.

So my question is: Using XAML, **how can I set the .Command property of the button inside my user control?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a dependency property to your UserControl and bind the button's Command property to that.

So in your GreatUserControl:

```
public ICommand SomeCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SomeCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SomeCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SomeCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(GreatUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

And in your GreatUserControl's XAML:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Whatever.GreatUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="me"
    >
    <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand,ElementName=me}">Click Me!</Button>
</UserControl>
```

So your button binds to the command on the UserControl itself. Now you can set that in your parent window:

```
<my:GreatUserControl SomeCommand="{Binding SomeCommandHere}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I realized part ways through I could do this by registering a DependencyProperty, but I was hoping there was an easier way (e.g. maybe expose the Button as a property of the control) then just set it in XAML. Anyways. This will do. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This breaks when you add a DataContext to your user control.

Comment: Patient: "It hurts when I do this." Doctor: "Stop doing that."

Comment: This pattern works great.  I was missing ElementName= and I wasnot naming my user control.

Comment: If you need a DataContext on some part of the user control, say a Grid, then I found that this works:  <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:NameOfUserControlHere}}}"></Grid>. This should be roughly equivalent to using DataContext = this; in code-behind, without breaking the user control. Along with the code above in the answer, the button will fire too as expected.